# Model and Membership Provider MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I need your help in guiding may into good way of implement the Model in MVC4.
I will let you see my model. But I really don’t know how to link that to Membership Provider in MVC4 
I want to build tender application system and I have the following models

- Tender: who add projects?
- Supplier/provider : who bid for projects
- Projects: Projects added by tenders    ( Done)
- Requirements: each projects had several requirements.(Done)

  1. I did the project And requirement Model.. But am not sure how to do the tender and suppliers!! Because both of them have to register ..!?

  2.Is my relation many to many is correct? Between Project and Requirement table.?

Now those are my model with context:

```
   public class ProjectContext : DbContext
{
    public ProjectContext()
        : base("ProjectsDB")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ProjectEntry> Entries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Requiernments> RequiernmentEntries { get; set; }
    //public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }



}





     public class ProjectEntry
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Statue {get; set; }
    public string UplodedFiles { get; set; }
    public string Budget { get; set; }
    public string EstimateTime { get; set; }
    public string Criterias { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }

}


            public class Requiernments
{
                            [Key]
                            public int RequiernmentId { get; set; }
                            public int ID { get; set; }

                            public string RequiernmentName { get; set; }

                            /// <summary>
                            /// 1: Must to Have 
                            /// 2: Nice to Have 
                            /// 3: Should have
                            /// </summary>
                            public string RequiernmentType { get; set; }

                            public string RequiernmentPrioritet { get; set; }

                            public float RequiernmenWhight { get; set; }
                            public string ProviderAnswer { get; set; }
                            public string ProviderComments{ get; set; }



}:
```

update 2:

```
  // POST: /Account/Register

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {

                if (!Roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
                    Roles.CreateRole("Admin");

                if (!Roles.RoleExists("Member"))
                    Roles.CreateRole("Member");

                if (!Roles.RoleExists("Tender"))
                    Roles.CreateRole("Tender");

                if (!Roles.RoleExists("Provider"))
                    Roles.CreateRole("Provider");

                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password,
                     new
                     {
                         EmailAddress = model.EmailAddress
                     }, false);
                Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "Member");
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

AND

```
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=user-Pc\SQL2012;Initial       Catalog=MemberDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MemberDB.mdf"   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />




 </connectionStrings>
```

image:

```
    http://i58.tinypic.com/2rp8i86.png
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, in your application you have two roles, **tender** and **supplier**. In addition, you want to **tender** to be able to add **project** and then associate **requirements** with **project**.

In order to achieve that, first of all you need to config **SimpleMembershipProvider** to have two roles "**tender**" and "**supplier**"

1. First in the configuration file, replace the classic membership provider with **SimpleMembershipProvider** by doing this
2. enable migrations
3. seed membership and roles

   ```
   protected override void Seed(MovieDb context)
   {            
   //context.Movies.AddOrUpdate(...);

   // ...

       SeedMembership();
   }

   private void SeedMembership()
   {            
       WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection",
           "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

   var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider) Roles.Provider;
   var membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider) Membership.Provider;

   if (!roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
   {
       roles.CreateRole("Admin");
   }
   if (membership.GetUser("sallen",false) == null)
   {
       membership.CreateUserAndAccount("sallen", "imalittleteapot");
   }
   if (!roles.GetRolesForUser("sallen").Contains("Admin"))
   {
       roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] {"sallen"}, new[] {"admin"});
   }
   ```

   }

step 1,2,3 reference:
[Scott Allen's blog](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/09/05/seeding-membership-amp-roles-in-asp-net-mvc-4.aspx)

1. Now create your model

   ```
   public class Tender
   {
       public int TenderId { get;set;} 
       public int UserId {get;set;}  //this links to the userid in the UserProfiles table
       public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects {get;set;} 
   }

   public class Project
   {
       public int ProjectId {get;set;}
       public int TenderId {get;set;}

       public virtual Tender Tender {get;set;}
       public virtual ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers {get;set;}
       public virtual ICollection<Requirement> Requirements {get;set;}
   }

   public class Supplier
   {  
       public int SupplierId {get;set;}

       public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects {get;set;}
   }

   public class Requirement
   {
        public int RequirmentId {get;set;}
        public int ProjectId {get;set;}

        public virtual Project Project {get;set;}
   }
   ```

because supplier can bid multiple projects and projects can have multiple bidders, therefore supplier and project have a multiple to multiple relationship, you probably want to have a mapping table.

In the OnModelCreating Method,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
                .HasMany(p => p.Suppliers)
                .WithMany(s => s.Projects)
                .Map(map =>
                {
                    map.ToTable("Project_Supplier_Map")
                       .MapLeftKey("SupplierId")
                       .MapRightKey("ProjectId");
                });
```

Now you have your model and just need to decorate your class with Authorize attribute

Comment: so, is oky to have 2 database? I have one projectcontext which create projectDB(Project,requirement tables)  and and another default connection ...?I already have (  Account model,Account Controller, Account view)...by default( I think this what you called Simple Membership...right?) .....

Comment: No. the one you got is classic membershipprovider. I recommend to use SimpleMembershipProvider, once again, please refer to Scott Allen's blog. http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/09/05/seeding-membership-amp-roles-in-asp-net-mvc-4.aspx

Comment: but using classic membershipprovider you already have all required tables ....I think that much better...right?

Comment: Well, yes you're right. The reason why I recommend using SimpleMembershipProvider is because you're using ASP.NET MVC4 framework which supports it. But whatever membershipprovider is not the point for your question, the point is put a userId property in the tender model which links the user to the tender.

Comment: I still not getting it ..referring to your solution.. how many database I will have ?2 or one ?  .see update 2

Comment: I think you get mix up ...I think what i have called SimpleMembershipProvider Not Classic membershipprovider.!